# How dont create stream each time after change input?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following code:

```
public upload(): void {
    const fileinput = document.getElementById('file');
    fileinput.click();
    fileinput.addEventListener('change', this.handleFileInput.bind(this));
}

private handleFileInput(event) {
    try {
        const input = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
        const reader = new FileReader();
        const { objectId } = this.object;
        const file = input.files[0];

        reader.onload = () => {
            event.target.value = null;
            this.objectDetailsService
                .upload(file, objectId)
                .subscribe(
                    () => //,
                    () => //,
                );
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

I should allow to load the same file sometimes. When user select another this code create as new stream. How to avoid it?

Comment: How to apply swithMap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right in asking how to apply `switchMap`. One way is to create an observable to handle the async callback `onload`. Then you could apply operators like `switchMap` to call other async functions.

Also I'd suggest attaching the event handler directly in the template instead of using `document.getElementById('file');` in the controller.

Try the following

***.ts**

```js
import { Observable, Observer, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

public handleFileInput(event) {
  const input = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
  const file = input.files[0];
  this.readFile(file).pipe(
    switchMap((file: any) => {
      const { objectId } = this.object;
      return this.objectDetailsService.upload(file, objectId);
    })
  ).subscribe({
    next: () => console.log('File uploaded'),
    error: (error: any) => console.log('Error:', error),
  });
}

readFile(file): Observable<any> {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

  return new Observable((observer: Observer<any>) => {
    reader.onload = (ev: ProgressEvent) => {
      observer.next(file);
      observer.complete();
    };
    reader.onerror = (error: any) => {
      observer.error(error);
    };
  });
}
```

***.html**

```html
Select file: <input type="file" (change)="handleFileInput($event)" />
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eeecmn?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: I call it using click by:

`  
        const fileinput = document.getElementById('fileDvg');
        fileinput.click();
        fileinput.addEventListener('change', this.handleFileInput.bind(this));
    `

Comment: I have tested, your code calls server request twice

Comment: @Jessy: Using `document.getElementById()` in Angular would sweep the entire app DOM instead of just the respective component template. I don't see any advantage in using it in your use case.

Comment: I try to open dialog upload by click by another element, how to do that?

Comment: @Jessy: How do you say it's calling twice? I don't see anything here to trigger the request twice. In fact, the `switchMap` would make sure the previous request gets cancelled, if any such exists, before triggering the next request.

Comment: @Jessy: I'd say that's another question unrelated to the issue at hand. If you'd like a better solution for it please post another question with relevant details.